# showing an element by id from a shopify page

Tags: shopify, liquid

so, I managed to run into a wall here, I don't know what to do since I'm new to liquid from shopify:
in the description of product.liquid I added some tabs to organize all a bit better, the tabs are description, shipping, and reviews.

In the description tab appears: {{ product.description }}.

In the shipping tab appears {{ pages.shipping.content }} (since I've made a page which content will show in all products).

but in reviews, i had the idea of  making a page which content would be like:

```
<p id="product1_name">product review text here</p>
<p id="product2_name">product review text here</p>
<p id="product3_name">product review text here</p>
```

and in the review tab would be some code similar to {{ pages.review.content ONLY-ELEMENT-WITH-ID=product.title}} so we could add all the reviews in a page and all the products will show the correspondent data.

I really hope I could explain myself.
and thanks a lot in advance, I been trying to solve it for endless hours T_T

Comment: If you are using the Shopify built Reviews App the instructions are here https://help.shopify.com/manual/apps/apps-by-shopify/product-reviews/installation

Comment: Oh no, I'm not using it since I've seen that tends to import horribly written reviews from AliExpress, I intend to hand pick them and put them in a page and accessing them dynamically

Comment: now i see what you mean, since im a starting dropshipping store, I intend to copy some good reviews from aliexpress, and paste them in a custom page sorrounded by a <p id="ItemName">reviewtext</p>. Since i saw that i can show the content of a custom page, I also imagine that must be a way to only show a html element of one page as well, I just dont know liquid enough. BTW i just installed the build in reviews app, it will be good for begin gathering reviews from my costumers, thank you! :)

Comment: Oh then you'll probably have to use product metadata to put your reviews in. I don't know of a better way. https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/metafield